# Returning object in http response with NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse

I want to send an sql query result object from http server back to the client.
I get this error:
"TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer"

If I turn the response content into string it works fine, but then it becomes useless for me.

What is the solution for the problem? Maybe there another way of making http response, or something else?

```
retrieve.retrieveAllStores(function(data){ 
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
  res.write(data); 
  res.end(); 
});
```

Comment: Can you try checking the type of data with `console.log( typeof data )`

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` before sending data

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `JSON.stringify()` to convert data to a string and then using `JSON.parse()` to convert back to JS object.

```
retrieve.retrieveAllStores(function(data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you John! That is what I needed!